# php/mysql connection on different servers

Tags: php, mysql

I have a local and a remote server on which I am developing a project

```
//local
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "bob";
$password = "fred";
$dbname = "jane";

//remote
$servername = "arthur";
$username = "Milly";
$password = "Horace";
$dbname = "Erastus";
```

At the moment I am commenting out the //local or //remote bit depending which way I am connecting. Of course, I regularly overwrite the connection file by mistake which is a pain.

Is there some sort of way I can detect which server I am on, and then connect automatically. I have tried googling but couldn't turn anything up maybe because i couldn't think of the right search terms.

Thanks

Comment: how about using `sessions` and converting your variables into array?

Comment: Please mark the correct answer for which one that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:-

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "localhost") {
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "bob";
$password = "fred";
$dbname = "jane";
}
elseif ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "google.com") {
$servername = "arthur";
$username = "Milly";
$password = "Horace";
$dbname = "Erastus";
}
else {
echo "No configuration found!";
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more than a few ways of doing this but one you could try is to detect which server you are on from the IP Address

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1') {
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "bob";
  $password = "fred";
  $dbname = "jane";
} else {
   //remote
  $servername = "arthur";
  $username = "Milly";
  $password = "Horace";
  $dbname = "Erastus";
}
```

Comment: tried this but the SERVER_ADDR came back as ::1 - when I was expecting 127.0.0.1 - WAMP on  my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :-

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername1, $username1, $password1);
if (! $conn->connect_error) {
$conn = new mysqli($servername2, $username2, $password2);    
}
```

Or check :-

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="localhost"
```